# How to compare (min & max) Float values with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, comparison

I've a database with `lon` and `lat` *geo location* data.
Both are saved as `float` / `decimal` attribute in the [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) table.

Now I want to compare this stuff like:

```
(u.user_location_lat <= ".$lat_max." AND u.user_location_lat >= ".$lat_min.") AND
(u.user_location_long <= ".$long_max." AND u.user_location_long >=".$long_min.")
```

But it does not show any result (and it should!) - but also no error.

How to EASILY solve this (I actually don't want to work with `spatial` indexes - at least I do not understand how to do)?

Thanks.

Comment: Are they float OR decimal?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you verify what that statement looks like, after you do the variable substitution.

That is, `echo` or `vardump` the contents of the variable containing the SQL text, before you prepare/execute the SQL statement.

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the form of the predicates. (These could be written using equivalent BETWEEN comparators, but it's not a problem what you have written.)

It's possible you have the `min` and `max` values swapped, or have the longitude and latitude swapped.  If that's not the issue, then I suspect that the variables being substituted may be represented in scientific notation, rather than as decimal values.

e.g. the SQL text gets generated

```
  ...  u.lat <= 1.241E+2 ...
```

rather than

```
  ...  u.lat <= 124.1 ...
```

In the former case, MySQL is going to evaluate that literal as decimal value of 1.241.

(There's a corner case issue when the bounding box crosses the +180/-180 boundary, but I don't see that's likely a problem for most of your values, that's going to be an exceptional case, which you would probably need to setup special test case to actually have happen.)

In order to debug this, you need the actual SQL text that's being sent to the database to be prepared/executed.

(There's not enough information in your question to identify the actual problem.)

---

**Q:**  How do I get the actual SQL text?

**A:**  Construct your SQL statement as a string into a variable; and then `var_dump` that variable for debugging:

```
$sqltext = "SELECT ... WHERE u.lat <= ". $lat_max . " AND u.lat ... ";
var_dump($sqltext);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sqltext);
```

Comment: How do I get the actual SQL text?

Comment: $query  = "SELECT u.user_id,u.user_location_lat,u.user_location_long,p.user_id FROM users AS u, profiles AS p WHERE u.user_id = p.user_id AND (u.user_location_lat <= '".$lat_max."' AND u.user_location_lat >= '".$lat_min."') AND (u.user_location_long <= '".$long_max."' AND u.user_location_long >= '".$long_min."') GROUP BY u.user_id";
 $sql  = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
 var_dump($query);
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($database, $query);

Comment: resource(3) of type (mysql result) 500